# Get description of OID - SNMP

Tags: snmp

I'm trying to read data off a Cisco Meraki MX84 using SNMP. I can successfully get data from the oids using snmpget and the OSX tool MIBBrowser. The problem I'm having is that the oid is hard to interpret. Is there a command I can run with snmpwalk or using another tool to see the human readable description of each oid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the MIB to get the information about the MIB objects (including their name, meaning, etc). A google search "Cisco Meraki MIB" will give you the answer.